# Generate Email from Excel Data with Lotus Notes Social Edition Home

Tags: vba, excel, email, lotus-notes

So I've been trying to come up with a macro to send a emails with a attachment through a spread sheet.

For example:

`mailto:emailadress@email.com?subject=Sample12345`

If I use the above string in excel it will prompt my default email client to create the email with the example email address and sample subject line.
I've used it for a while and it might be simple string but, its super helpful when I can manipulate it in excel.

Example of string manipulating in a cell  : `=HYPERLINK(A1&A2&A3&A4&A5&A6)`

I would like to morph the same concept but ,in a macro so I can send it to multiple people with a different email address.

The problems :

I have Lotus Notes Social Edition Home as default email client - Release 9.0.1

Example of what I would like to accomplish :

```
Mailto: sampleemailadress@email.com (from a specific cell value in excel "=Sheet1!A1")
CC:( from a specific cell value in excel "=Sheet1!A2" )
Body: ( from a specific Range in excel "=Sheet2!A1:B24" )
Attachment : (from a specific cell value in excel "=Sheet1!A1") ....Value in Cell - " C:\Users\User1\Downloads\sampleexcelsheet.xlsm "
```

Let me know your thoughts.

Thank you!.

Comment: do you have outlook installed at all?

Comment: I do have Outlook installed but, since I have allot of archive past emails I would hate to change email client at this point.                                                           any thoughts?

Comment: This is very simple with Outlook. If you can use outlook to only send this mails that would be a lot easier and there's loads of examples online how to do that.

Comment: Agreed on the simplicity of using Outlook but, would there be a way under references in Excel a Object library option that could help use a default email client?

Comment: Use Word mail merge with the Excel data as the source. Merge to email. Done.

Comment: Does [this page](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/73766-create-email-but-dont-send-lotus-notes.html) help? I use Lotus also and have a macro that takes Excel data and puts into an email, based off of that page.

Comment: @teylyn , I've tried mail merge but, since I work off a excel workbook. It would be easy to just click a button for a macro since everything auto populating into would I would need to send out.In addition I don't believe mail merge could attache a pdf,excel or zip file to send with any email.     Thank you though.

Comment: @BruceWayne , Thank you for that much appreciated but, it seems to be unique to a specific email address ,subject and specific directory path.  would it be easy to just change those fields?

Comment: What do you mean it's unique to a specific email?  You can set up variables to store the data from your Excel sheet and go from there, no?

Comment: under MailDoc.SendTo = "email@web.com" and would it be possible to have call out a cell?

Comment: Word has it all built-in. If you want to re-invent the wheel, suit yourself.

Comment: @teylyn - Some of us are stuck in Lotus :(  I've reinvented at least three wheels because of it.  Must say, it helps my VBA learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more bare-bones way to send an email. It works for me, I have Lotus Notes 9 so hopefully it also works for your version.

```
Sub Send_Email_via_Lotus()
'Send an e-mail & attachment using Lotus Not(s)
'Original Code by Nate Oliver (NateO)
'Declare Variables for file and macro setup
'Dim AVal As Variant
Dim UserName As String, MailDbName As String, ccRecipient As String, Recipient As String
Dim Maildb As Object, MailDoc As Object, Session As Object
Dim email As String, bodyText As String, clientRef As String, bodyRng As Range, emailBody As String
Dim notesUIDoc As Object

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False

    ' Open and locate current LOTUS NOTES User
    Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    UserName = Session.UserName
    MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"
    Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", MailDbName)
    If Maildb.IsOpen = True Then
    Else
        Call Maildb.OPENMAIL
    End If

    Recipient = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    ccRecipient = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    Set bodyRng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B24")

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In bodyRng
        emailBody = emailBody & " " & cel.Value
    Next cel

    ' Create New Mail and Address Title Handlers
    Set MailDoc = Maildb.CreateDocument
    MailDoc.Form = "Memo"
    MailDoc.sendTo = Recipient
    MailDoc.CopyTo = ccRecipient
    MailDoc.Subject = "SUBJECT HERE"

    'Displays email message without sending; user needs to click Send
    Set workspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
    Set notesUIDoc = workspace.EditDocument(True, MailDoc)
    'Call notesUIDoc.FieldClear("Body") '' This line will clear the ENTIRE body, including signature.
    Call notesUIDoc.gotofield("Body") 'This should just Go to the body, keeping your signature.
    Call notesUIDoc.FieldAppendText("Body", emailBody)

    Set Maildb = Nothing
    Set MailDoc = Nothing
    Set AttachME = Nothing
    Set Session = Nothing
    Set EmbedObj1 = Nothing

    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

'End If
Exit Sub

errorhandler1:
Set Maildb = Nothing
Set MailDoc = Nothing
Set AttachME = Nothing
Set Session = Nothing
Set EmbedObj1 = Nothing
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Note that the Attachment part is lacking, I'll keep searching for that but this should get you started, and see how you can use the variables to set the body, recipients, etc.  (There may be unnecessary variables too, I didn't quite check those).

NOTE: Please review the `For Each cel in bodyRng` loop, as I don't quite know how you want the body set up.

Comment: .Great , I got it to work but, it clears my signature and the body formats is weird.?any thoughts?

Comment: @Boomer - The body formatting will depend on how you set it up in that `For` loop.  Note you can add in some `vbCrLf` to get a line break, like `emailBody = "Hello John," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "This is an email."`.  Give me a second and I'll edit the code so it keeps your signature.

Comment: I got it to work with attaching "2" attachments and without clearing out my signature. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```html
Sub NotesEmailrun()

Dim UserName As String, MailDbName As String, ccRecipient As String, attachment1 As String
Dim Maildb As Object, MailDoc As Object, AttachME As Object, Session As Object
Dim EmbedObj1 As Object


With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.DisplayAlerts = False


Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
UserName = Session.UserName
MailDbName = _
Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"
Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", "")
If Maildb.IsOpen = True Then
Else
Maildb.OpenMail
End If


Set MailDoc = Maildb.CreateDocument
MailDoc.Form = "Memo"

MailDoc.Sendto = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
MailDoc.CopyTo = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

MailDoc.Subject = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Value
MailDoc.body = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:H24")


MailDoc.SaveMessageOnSend = True

attachment1 = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\folder1\time.txt"
If attachment1 <> "" Then
On Error Resume Next
Set AttachME = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("attachment1")
Set EmbedObj1 = AttachME.EmbedObject(1454, "", attachment1)
On Error Resume Next
End If

attachment2 = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder2\time2.txt"
If attachment2 <> "" Then
On Error Resume Next
Set AttachME = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("attachment2")
Set EmbedObj1 = AttachME.EmbedObject(1454, "", attachment2)
On Error Resume Next
End If


Set workspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Call workspace.EditDocument(True, MailDoc).GOTOFIELD("Body")


Set Maildb = Nothing
Set MailDoc = Nothing
Set AttachME = Nothing
Set Session = Nothing
Set EmbedObj1 = Nothing

.ScreenUpdating = True
.DisplayAlerts = True
End With

errorhandler1:

Set Maildb = Nothing
Set MailDoc = Nothing
Set AttachME = Nothing
Set Session = Nothing
Set EmbedObj1 = Nothing

End Sub
```